# Cannot read a property ("null") of a DIV just created in JS after button click

Tags: javascript, html, null

I'm trying to create a basic web page that allows users to create a new DIV when the button pressed. I completed that part successfully. Now to find the individual DIV when pressed (so I can apply other features later like editing it), without using extensive repeated code, I created/ designed a system that compares the colour of a DIV being hovered over and finds the ID for it. However, the colour assigned to the DIV remains null apparently although you can see the CSS changes the colour of it. Any suggestions? Sorry if my code is displayed horribly; first time writing a question on here.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/scripts.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form onsubmit="createNewContentTile(); return false;">
        <input type="submit" id="addTile" value="+">
        <input type="text" id="inputTextContent" placeholder="content" maxlength="256">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
var tileDivIDCounter = 0;
var arrayOfTileIDs = ["tileDiv1"];
var selectTileDivIDCounter = 0;
var selectedTile = "";

function tileClicked() {
    while (document.getElementById(arrayOfTileIDs[selectTileDivIDCounter]).style.backgroundcolor === "#ff0000") {
        selectedTile = arrayOfTileIDs[selectTileDivIDCounter];
        alert(arrayOfTileIDs[selectTileDivIDCounter]);
    }
    selectTileDivIDCounter += 1;
}

function createNewContentTile() {
    if (document.getElementById("inputTextContent").value === "") {
        alert("Enter content");
    } else {
        tileDivIDCounter += 1;
        tileDivIDString = "tileDivID" + tileDivIDCounter;
        arrayOfTileIDs.push(tileDivIDString);
        var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
        newDiv.setAttribute("class", "tileDiv");
        newDiv.setAttribute("id", tileDivIDString);
        newDiv.setAttribute("onclick", "tileClicked()");
        var inputText = document.getElementById("inputTextContent").value;
        var newContent = document.createTextNode(inputText);
        document.getElementById("inputTextContent").value = "";
        newDiv.appendChild(newContent);
        var currentDiv = document.getElementById("div1");
        document.body.insertBefore(newDiv, currentDiv);      //change to bottom of wrapper
    }


}
```

CSS:

```
.tileDiv {
background-color: aqua;
}

.tileDiv:hover {
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

Comment: Your element `id` is called `"tileDivID"` in `createNewContentTitle()`, but you reference `tileDiv1` in `tileClicked()`.

Comment: Are you using the hover color as an indication of which `<div>` to edit? Why not use the `onMouseOver` event trigger?

Comment: That would work in another scenario however each a function would be required for each onMouseOver Event Trigger and as there is no limit to the amount of DIVs created it would not be dynamic if that makes sense. thanks tho.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two problems with what you're trying to do:

1) Style and computed style are two different things.  Simply applying a CSS styling to an element won't change the style attribute.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

2) selectTileDivIDCounter never gets changed so will always be set to 0, pointing at an element that doesn't exist (that's why you're getting null)

Edit:

Point 2 is not completely correct, because it does get incremented in the onclick function.  There might be some naming issues there, I'm not sure.  I think the main issue might be point #1, though.

Comment: I understand now thank you. I believe the method I have tried is not possible so will try another way. cheers

Answer (score -1):

From [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style)

> The HTMLElement.style property is used to get as well as set the inline style of an element

Because your element's background color is given by the css class, the tileDiv's inline style remains empty and so `tileDiv.style.backgroundColor` is `""`

To retrieve the all currently computed styles (CSS Attributes) of an HTMLElement use

```
window.getComputedStyle(div)
```

To get the currently computed background color use

```
window.getComputedStyle(div).backgroundColor
```

or

```
window.getComputedStyle(div).getPropertyValue('background-color')
```

with `div` being your element selected.

Comment: The OP is getting an error stating that the `style` property can't be gotten on  `null` element. It's not that the `style` is `undefined`.

Comment: "However, the colour assigned to the DIV remains null apparently". I didn't have the impression that the OP is having an error here. You are right though. I guess my answer just solved his next problem, because style.backgroundColor still won't work.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback but as I am not familiar with this I can't figure where to implement this. Where would I put these code snippets?

Comment: You put them in the while loop in `tileClicked`. The style attribute will always be `""` on that div, because you didn't set inline styles when you created the tile.

Comment: Parameter 1 is not type 'Element'

function tileClicked() {
    while (window.getComputedStyle(arrayOfTileIDs[selectTileDivIDCounter]).backgroundColor === "#ff0000") {
        selectedTile = arrayOfTileIDs[selectTileDivIDCounter];
        alert(arrayOfTileIDs[selectTileDivIDCounter]);
    }
    selectTileDivIDCounter += 1;
}

Comment: You have to call getComputedStyle an HTMLElement, right now you're calling it with an id...